# What is an alternative to making API calls every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the following method to make a call to the Google Drive API and pull a bunch of file names from my Drive account. This method currently gets run on every request which is obviously not good at all. What's the best alternative to prevent this and speed up the application?

```
  def get_all_scripts
    arr = []
    session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("config.json")
    session.collection_by_title("Input Sheets").spreadsheets.each do |sheet|
     arr << sheet.title
    end
    arr
  end
```

I'm using that array of file names inside of a form dropdown.

Comment: Hard to answer without more information. Why do you need this list on every request? Would it be okay to cache this list and only reload it every e.g. 10 minutes? How often does the list change? How does the list change (by this app or externally)?

Comment: Good point - it changes whenever a new product is added, so not very often. I think adding that method into a scheduled task would be a great option with an additional button that will refresh the list if needed, thank you!

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Answer (score 1):

How often is `get_all_scripts` run? If it's very frequent you can take a look at Google Drive [watch notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push). This will send you a message letting you know something has changed on the google drive side. You can now cache the results from the api request and every time you get a notification from the watch api you invalidate the cache so it is redownloaded next request.